# iphone webview and iframe issues

Tags: javascript, iphone, iframe, webview

I'm creating a "web loader" for an iphone app.  An html file is bundled with the iphone app and loaded into a webview.  In `webViewDidFinishLoad` i use `stringByEvaluatingJavascriptFromString` to execute a javascript function that creates an iframe, waits for it to load and then transitions it onto the screen.  It seems the process of creating the iframe causes `webViewDidFinishLoad` to constantly be called over and over and over again.  Has anyone experienced this problem or have a tip to identify how i might create an iframe via javascript without triggering this bug?

HTML file js code looks like so:

```
var ifrm;

function load(url) {
 ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
 ifrm.setAttribute("src", url); 
 ifrm.style.width = "100%"; 
 ifrm.style.height = "100%"; 
 ifrm.style.display = "none";
 ifrm.onload = function () {
     document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
     ifrm.style.display = '';
 }
 document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the iframe created in javascript was causing a second webViewDidFinishLoad method to fire.  I was incorrectly calling my js function again in this method which would cause a new iframe to be created and cause the looping behaviour.  I simply ignored the second call of this method and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really on native iphone app. But in a normal page you can do the opposite.

Load the `iframe` without `onload` event, and in a `script` tag at the end of the `body` of the loaded document, call the parent, like:

```
<body>
  ...
  <script>
    //the document is loaded
    //call a function in the parent page
    parent.appObj.iframeLoadedCallback(window);
  </script>
</body>
```